# Are address of object and pointer to object the same thing for an object of polymorph class?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

I was trying to solve a c++ test, and saw this question.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A() : m_i(0) { }

protected:
    int m_i;
};

class B
{
public:
    B() : m_d(0.0) { }

protected:
    double m_d;
};

class C
    : public A
    , public B
{
public:
    C() : m_c('a') { }

private:
    char m_c;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    A *pa = &c;
    B *pb = &c;

    const int x = (pa == &c) ? 1 : 2;
    const int y = (pb == &c) ? 3 : 4;
    const int z = (reinterpret_cast<char*>(pa) == reinterpret_cast<char*>(pb)) ? 5 : 6;

    std::cout << x << y << z << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/677e3b3b48d0b2c7) :

```
136
```

Can anyone explain it's output? I thought the base pointer points to the part of the base part, so it's not the real address of the object.

Thanks.

Comment: Added the output - thank you for a snippet that actually is a MCVE :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pa` points to `A` subobject of `c`. `pb` points to `B` subobject of `c`. Obviously, they point to different locations in memory (so `6` in the output).

But when they are compared to `&c`, `&c` is again converted to `A*` and `B*` respectively, thus pointing to the same `A` and `B` subobject.

Here's for illustration the likely layout of `c` in memory:

```
+------------------------+-------------+-------------------+
| A subobject            | B subobject | Remainder of C    |
+------------------------+-------------+-------------------+
^ &c is here             ^ pb points here
^ pa also points here
```

Comment: `&c` is converted to `A*` and `B*`, respectively, and the subobject addresses are compared. Unless someone snuck in a magic implicit downward conversion while nobody was looking.

Comment: Are you sure about this structure? Or that's just an example?

Comment: @GrigorApoyan this is what most likely the compiler generates in practice (provided there's no virtual inheritance going on)

Answer (score 2):

**Background**

Object C looks something like this in memory

```
    -----------  <----- Start of the object
    |    A    |
    |---------|  <----- Beginning of B implementation
    |    B    |
    |---------|
    |    C    |
    |_________|  <----- End of the object
```

When you take a pointer to a base class from a derived class (e.g. A* pa = &c), the pointer points to the beginning of that class implementation for that object.

So this means A* will point to the beginning of A (which happens to be the beginning of the object) and B* will point to the beginning of B. Note that C* will not point to the beginning of C because it knows that C is derived from A and B. It will point to the beginning of the object.

**Why?**

Because when you call pb->someFunction(), it actually takes the pointer pointing to B and adds some precalculated offset and executes. If pb was pointing to the beginning of A, then it would end up in inside A. The pre-calculated offset is necessary because you have no idea what pb actually points to (is it C, is it "D", or just plain old B?). This approach allows us to always rely on the offset for finding the function.

**Here's what your code is really doing**

```
((A*)pa == (A*)&c) // Obviously true, since we defined it as such above.
((B*)pb == (B*)&c) // Obviously true, since we defined it as such above.
(reinterpret_cast<char*>(pa) == reinterpret_cast<char*>(pb)) // We know pa and pb point to different places in memory. If we cast them both to char*, they will obviously not be equivalent.
```

An interesting thing to try is

```
if (pa == pb)
```

This will give you a compilation error because you need to cast both pointers to a common type.